# ¿Cómo barajear aleatoriamente un array?

Tags: lenguaje-agnóstico

Teniendo un array como este:

```
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

¿Cómo podria cambiar su **orden** de manera **aleatoria**?

Estaría bien responder de un modo genérico para que sirva como ejemplo de implementación para cualquier lenguaje

[Cambiar el orden de los datos del array dentro del mismo]

---

*La pregunta originalmente preguntaba sobre js y jQuery.

---

PD: Esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) ya existe en la version inglesa, pero me parecia interesante retomarla y adaptarla para usuarios hispanohablantes. Dejare un tiempo para que la gente pueda aportar una respuesta. En caso de no haberlas, traducire la respuesta mas optima y añadire aportes de la casa.

Comment: Eh... jQuery no es un lenguaje, y podríamos incluso responder la pregunta de un modo genérico para que sirva como ejemplo de implementación para cualquier lenguaje

Comment: @GDP existe el tag [tag:lenguaje-agnóstico]

Comment: @GDP - Por lo visto haz editado esto varias veces.. quitare el voto del cierre... (opinion personal: no me gustan esas copias y pegas literalmente de SO ... quizás sería mejor de generar la pregunta y la respuesta al mismo tiempo y convertirlo en wiki... pero lo dicho opinion personal)

Comment: @aldanux no pongo la respuesta inmediatamente porque creo que se puede incluso mejorar la de SO. Seria interesante saber que puede aportar la gente, y en caso de que no haya algo igual o mejor entonces si.

Comment: Lo dudo mucho que alguien reinventa la rueda... ejemplo...la [respuesta de Aitor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18650169/2097224)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como es una pregunta que puede tener una respuesta diferente segun el lenguaje, vamos a hablar de algoritmos, sin importar el lenguaje (inclusive se podria decir que se puede hacer en una base de datos).

Una de las formas que mas me gusta a mi para mezclar un vector (u obtener todos sus datos desordenados), y no es del todo performante pero sirve, es generar un nuevo vector de mezcla, y combinar los mismos.

Digamos que tenemos un vector de números (1,2,3...100) y queremos mezclarlo.. Cada numero tiene un indice en el vector (en este caso el indice seria igual al mismo numero).. Utilizamos una matriz con posiciones de la siguiente forma

```
posicion orden
1
2
3
...
100
```

y lo que vamos a hacer, es para cada fila de esta matriz generar un numero aleatorio que va en la columna orden. La generación del numero aleatorio debe ser lo bastante amplia como para cubrir la cantidad de casos a mezclar.

De esa forma, nos podría quedar una cosa así:

```
posición orden
1        54
2        29
3        14 
...
100      54
```

Luego de esto, hacemos un sort de esta matriz, por la columna orden:

```
posición orden
3        14
2        29
1        54
100      54
...
```

Notese que si dos posiciones tienen el mismo orden, no importa, ya que igual se estarían mezclando. Obviamente se puede usar una función aleatoria que devuelva casos donde casi no habría colisiones.

Una vez concluido este proceso, dependendiendo del uso que se quiera dar al vector original, se puede regenerar las posiciones utilizando el nuevo orden dado por la matriz, o simplemente se pueden sacar los items necesarios en el orden dado por la nueva matriz.

Answer (score 10):

**AVISO**

> No es recomendable utilizar este metodo con elementos grandes, ya que no es un metodo muy eficaz. Pero para arrays simples no hay ningún problema.

Hay una manera muy simple de hacerlo en [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript).

```js
var arr1 = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
arr1.sort(function() { return Math.random() - 0.5 });
console.log(arr1)
```

**Explicación:**

La función [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Math/random) nos devuelve un número aleatorio entre 0 y 0.9999..., lo que conseguimos al restarle 0.5 es que nos genere números negativos y positivos para que la función `sort()` nos re-ordene el array de forma aleatoria colocando un elemento delante otro detrás.

Answer (score 2):

Otras soluciones aportadas dependen de una llamada a `sort()`. Si el lenguaje con que trabajas tiene implementada esa función, puede ser una buena solución. Sin embargo si trabajas en lenguajes que no disponen de `sort()`, tendrías que implementar tú una, lo que complicaría innecesariamente el problema. Además esta solución tendría complejidad mayor de O(N), pues es necesario primero un bucle de complejidad O(N) para generar los números aleatorios y luego otro de complejidad O(N·log(N)) para ordenarlos (suponiendo que se usa el algoritmo de ordenación QuickSort, que es uno de los más óptimos posibles y el que está implementado en la mayoría de los lenguajes)-

Se me ha ocurrido otro algoritmo sencillo que no depende de `sort()` y que tiene complejidad O(N), que es el siguiente:

- Sea N la longitud del array menos 1
- Repetir mientras N > 0:

  - Generar un número aleatorio R entre 0 y N (ambos inclusive)
  - Intercambiar los elementos en posición R y N
  - Decrementar N

El algoritmo parte de la siguiente idea. Imagina que tienes un mazo de cartas real. Una forma muy simple de mezclarlas sería ir tomando cartas al azar del mazo y dejándolas sobre la mesa, una encima de otra. Una vez todas están en la mesa, estarán mezcladas. En cada "iteración" de este bucle te van quedando menos cartas en la mano.

Una simulación literal de esto sería tomar un elemento al azar de la lista y llevarlo a otro array (la "mesa" donde se dejan las cartas). Después, para completar la simulación de que se ha extraido una carta, el array original debe "menguar", lo que se implementaría desplazando una posición atrás todos los elementos del array original a partir del elemento elegido.

El algoritmo que propongo se ahorra el desplazamiento, moviendo en su lugar al hueco el último dato de la lista. Esto va cambiando la lista original cada vez que se elige un elemento, pero lo mismo nos da que esté desordenada con respecto a su estado inicial ¡estamos barajando! También nos ahorramos la segunda lista usando como "mesa" la propia lista, en sus posiciones finales. Es por tanto eficiente en tiempo y en memoria, al usar una única lista.

Una implementación (por ejemplo en Python) sería:

```
import random

def barajar(lista):
  N = len(lista)-1
  while N > 0:
     R = random.randint(0,N)
     aux = lista[R]
     lista[R] = lista[N]
     lista[N] = aux
     N-=1

# Demo
lista = list(range(20))  # numeros del 0 al 19 ordenados
barajar(lista)
print(lista)
```

Produce por ejemplo:

```
[3, 5, 14, 6, 12, 18, 11, 15, 7, 4, 2, 8, 17, 9, 1, 0, 19, 16, 10, 13]
```

### Edición

Tras investigar un poco descubro que (obviamente) el algoritmo se le había ocurrido antes a otro :-) Concretamente, se trata del [algoritmo de Fisher-Yates](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Fisher-Yates), popularizado por Donald Knuth en su libro *The art of computer programming*. Parece ser que es un algoritmo muy usado, por ser óptimo en espacio y en tiempo de ejecución.

Answer (score 1):

Utilizo este código en Android para permutar un Array sin repetición.

```
private int pos[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};

permutaSinRepe(0,9); //Llamada a la función

private void permutaSinRepe(int min,int max){

    int Temp;
    Random r = new Random();

    for(int i=min;i <= max;i++){

       //Genero un indice aleatorio entre el minimo y el maximo
       int ind = r.nextInt(max - min) + min; 

       //Realizo la permutación del Array
       Temp = pos[i];
       pos[i] = pos[ind];
       pos[ind] = Temp;

    }

}
```