# ¿Como puedo hacer para que tarjetas de un juego de memorama se ordenen de forma aleatoria al fallar?

Tags: c#

Hola  estoy tratando de hacer un juego de memorama en c#, lo tengo casi completo pero solo me hace falta que cuando dos pares de tarjetas seleccionadas sean diferentes las tarjetas se ordenen de otra manera. alguien que me pueda ayudar.
Aqui parte del codigo:

```
private void btncarta_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cartasseleccionadas.Count < 2)
    {


        movimientos++;
        label3.Text = Convert.ToString(movimientos);
        var cartasseleccionadasusuario = (PictureBox)sender;
        cartaactual = Convert.ToInt32(cartasrevueltas[Convert.ToInt32(cartasseleccionadasusuario.Name) - 1]);
        cartasseleccionadasusuario.Image = recuperarimagen(cartaactual);
        cartasseleccionadas.Add(cartasseleccionadasusuario);
        if(cartasseleccionadas.Count==2)
        {
            cartatemporal1 = (PictureBox)cartasseleccionadas[0];
            cartatemporal2 = (PictureBox)cartasseleccionadas[1];
            int carta1 = Convert.ToInt32(cartasrevueltas[Convert.ToInt32(cartatemporal1.Name) - 1]);
            int carta2 = Convert.ToInt32(cartasrevueltas[Convert.ToInt32(cartatemporal2.Name) - 1]);
            if(carta1!=carta2)
            {
                timer1.Enabled = true;
                timer1.Start();


            }
            else
            {
                cantidaddecartasvolteadas++;
                if(cantidaddecartasvolteadas>7)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("El Juego Termino");
                }
                cartatemporal1.Enabled = false;
                cartatemporal2.Enabled = false;
                cartasseleccionadas.Clear();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: existe la clase random: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2 que es la que te permite generar numeros aleatorios

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Tenes que ser mas claro con tu pregunta. Poner el codigo relevante (no todo tu programa!) mostrar un ejemplo de lo que queres. Asi como esta, es dificil ayudarte

Comment: Lo se U. Busto pero no se como aplicarlo en este caso

Comment: tal vez esta [pregunta te de ideas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/103935/324)

Comment: Imaginemos que tienes 10 cartas, entonces podrias crear un array de 10 posiciones en la que el indice corresponde a la carta y el valor al orden para esa carta a la hora de pintar. Lo unico que tendrias que hacer en cada volteo es calcular aleatoriamente el valor de cada una de las posicones de array teniendo en cuenta que ese valor no se haya puesto ya, y luego pintar cada carta en la posicion que indique el valor asociado a su indice en el array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

suponiendo que tienes numeradas tus posiciones del 1 al 20 digamos,

llamas a una funcion que te devuelve un arreglo aleatorio de tus cartas:

```
  public IList<int>  arregloPosiciones(){
    int count=20;//posiciones
           List<int> randomNumbers = new List<int>(); 
            Random randomNumber = new Random();

    for (int i=0; i<count; i++) 
    {    
        int posicion;

        do posicion= randomNumber.Next(1, 21);
        while (randomNumbers.Contains(posicion));//busca repetidos

        randomNumbers.Add(posicion);//agrega un nuevo elemento
    }

    return randomNumbers;
    }
```