# Asignar un metodo en el constructor es asi?se hace en este o debo crear otro?

Tags: java

He tenido que crear un juego de Cartas y mas o menos la clase baraja la tengo. Ahora mi idea es asignar en el constructor al array de baraja el constructor de barajar para trabajar en el juego directamente con la baraja. Es una idea acepto sugerencias jajaj. mi problema es que no se como terminar el método barajar para poder meter el codigo en el constructor. os dejo el código

```
private CartaEspanyola[] b;
private int numCartasMazo;

public Baraja(CartaEspanyola[] b, int numCartasMazo) {
    this.b = barajar();
    this.numCartasMazo = numCartasMazo;
}

public Baraja() {
    this.b = new CartaEspanyola[40];
    CartaEspanyola c = null;
    numCartasMazo = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        switch (i / 10) {
            case 0: //Oros
                c = new CartaEspanyola(i % 10 + 1, "OROS");
                break;
            case 1: //Copas
                c = new CartaEspanyola(i % 10 + 1, "COPAS");
                break;
            case 2: //Espadas
                c = new CartaEspanyola(i % 10 + 1, "ESPADAS");
                break;
            case 3: //Bastos
                c = new CartaEspanyola(i % 10 + 1, "BASTOS");
                break;
        }
        this.b[i] = c;
        numCartasMazo++;
    }

}

public CartaEspanyola[] barajar() {
    Random r = new Random();
    int numCambios = 100 + r.nextInt(400);

    for (int i = 0; i < numCambios; i++) {
        int primera = r.nextInt(numCartasMazo);
        int segunda = r.nextInt(numCartasMazo);
        CartaEspanyola c = this.b[primera];
        this.b[primera] = this.b[segunda];
        this.b[segunda] = c;
    }

}

public CartaEspanyola getCarta() {
    CartaEspanyola c = null;
    if (numCartasMazo > 0 && b != null) {
        c = b[numCartasMazo - 1];
        b[numCartasMazo - 1] = null;
        numCartasMazo--;
    }
    return c;
}

public void setNumCartasMazo(int numCartasMazo) {
    this.numCartasMazo = numCartasMazo;
}

public CartaEspanyola[] getB() {
    return b;
}

public int getNumCartasMazo() {
    return numCartasMazo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String aux = "";

    for (int i = 0; i < numCartasMazo; i++) {
        aux += "\n" + b[i].toString();
    }
    return aux;
}
```

}

no se si es una barbaridad lo que pongo eh ajja gracias por la ayuda

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu problema. ¿Estás intentando crear una clase barajar utilizando programación orientada a objetos?

Comment: la idea es crear un juego de cartas luego n el main. tengo la clase carta la clase baraja y en la clase baraja quiero asignara en el constructor en el array el metodo barajar para tener la baraja lista pero no se si se hace asi y no se que poner de return en el metodo barajar

Comment: Viendo el código no queda claro que es lo que quieres hacer exactamente. Pon una explicación detallada de que es lo que deseas hacer para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que pretendes. Por el nombre del método intuyo que quieres mezclar tus cartas. Para barajear puedes hacerte un bucle, sacar un número random (entre 1 y 40) y situar la carta en ese lugar. Fijándome, lo haces con arrays, a lo mejor te conviene cambiarte al ArrayList para poder barajear sin problemas. Editado: Por cierto, tienes dos constructores, en uno de ellos "barajeas" y en el otro creas una nueva baraja. De momento barajear no surtirá efecto si juegas con ambos constructores

Comment: No puedo camibar a arraylist porque no lo he dado aun.

Comment: No entiendo cual es tu problema.. para barajar, mira esta pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/103935/324

Comment: Tampoco me queda clara la pregunta, pero me parece que el contructor con el array y el número de cartas no hace falta. Una vez que la baraja fue construida con llamar al metodo barajar las cartas de mezclan. También me parece que el método barajar no necesita devolver el array de cartas, la baraja debería proveer las cartas en el orden en que quedaron. (Y al usar random para bara barajar, en principio me parece que no hay diferencia entre hacer la mezcla de cartas 1 vez o 500)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si entendi bien la pregunta solo tienes que agregar el método barajar al final del constructor, quedaría asi:

```
public Baraja() {
   this.b = new CartaEspanyola[40];
   CartaEspanyola c = null;
   numCartasMazo = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
      switch (i / 10) {
         case 0: //Oros
            c = new CartaEspanyola(i % 10 + 1, "OROS");
            break;
         case 1: //Copas
            c = new CartaEspanyola(i % 10 + 1, "COPAS");
            break;
         case 2: //Espadas
            c = new CartaEspanyola(i % 10 + 1, "ESPADAS");
            break;
         case 3: //Bastos
            c = new CartaEspanyola(i % 10 + 1, "BASTOS");
            break;
      }
      this.b[i] = c;
      numCartasMazo++;
   }
   this.b = barajar();
}
```

y eliminas el otro constructor si no lo utilizarás

Comment: el cosntructor con parametros es basico porque debes sobrecargar los constructores o eso me han enseñado