# Generar valores aleatorios sin repetir en un juego de Dados c++

Tags: c++

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa en c++, el enunciado es el siguiente:

Realiza un programa en el que un usuario deba adivinar un numero. Nosotros tenemos que ponerle el rango de numero (usando ramdoms) pero definiendo los rangos (pedir RangoInicial y rangoFinal) OJO : no se debe repetir ningun numero random en lo que va del juego, por ultimo el usuario debe adivinar el numero.

Entiendo bien lo que se debe hacer pero el problema que tengo es en el momento de verificar los números ya repetidos. La idea que tengo es que cada Rango (resultado final del rangoinicial y final) sea almacenado en un vector con el tamanio final (rango final - rango inicial) para que asi pueda verificarse en un do while(si esta registrado no sale y genera otro).

La cuestión es que el programa se para y no avanza más. Aqui les dejo el avance del código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void definirRango(int &, int &);
void numAleatorio(int , int , int &, int [], int);

int aumentar = 0;

int main(){

    system("cls");
    srand (time(NULL));
    int in = 0,fin = 0, rango;

    cout<<"\n\n\t[DANDO RANGO DE NUMEROS]\n\n";
    definirRango(in,fin);
    int tam = fin-in;

    int contenedorRepetidos[tam];

    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tam);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tam);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tam);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tam);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tam);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}


void definirRango(int &lI, int &lS){

    cout<<"Ingresa Inicio de Rango : ";
    cin>>lI;

    cout<<"Ingresa Final de Rango : ";
    cin>>lS;

}

void numAleatorio(int lI, int lS, int &rango, int contenedorR[], int tam){

    int i =0;
    bool registrado = false;
    bool salir = false;
    
    do{
        rango = lI + rand() % (lS + 1 - lI); 
    
        for(i = 0; i < tam ; i++){
            if(contenedorR[i] == rango){
                registrado = true;
            }
        }

        if(registrado == false){
            contenedorR[aumentar] = rango;
            salir = true;
            aumentar++;
        }else{
            salir = false;
        }

    }while(salir != true);

}
```

Comment: Quizás lo más sencillo sea que pre-generes todos los números del rango,ordenados, en un array, y después "barajes" el array. Con el array barajado, basta ir leyendo sus elementos por orden, para tener cada vez uno distinto, y todos en el rango. Para barajar el array puedes tomar ideas de [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/434018/7123)

Comment: La idea de abulafia te vendria perfecta para tu problema. Te recomeindo que busques en internet `std::vector` y `std::shuffle`. Mucha suerte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A numAleatorio no le tienes que pasar el tamaño **total** sino sólo el tamaño **actual**: cuantos números llevas metidos.

Aparte de eso, deberías haber inicializado contenedorR; podría darse la mala suerte de que alguno de los valores sin inicializar coincidiera con un valor ya existente.

La variable salir no es necesaria en absoluto. Y la variable registrado debe inicializarse a falso en cada iteración, ya que de lo contrario, si el for no la actualiza, se queda permanentemente a registrado y no termina.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

void definirRango(int &, int &);
void numAleatorio(int , int , int &, int [], int &);
void inicializarContenedorRepetidos( int [], int & );

int aumentar = 0;

int main(){

    system("cls");
    srand (time(NULL));
    int in = 0,fin = 0, rango;

    cout<<"\n\n\t[DANDO RANGO DE NUMEROS]\n\n";
    definirRango(in,fin);
    int tamanioTotal = fin-in;
    int tamanioActual = 0;

    int contenedorRepetidos[tamanioTotal];

    inicializarContenedorRepetidos( contenedorRepetidos, tamanioTotal );

    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tamanioActual);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tamanioActual);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tamanioActual);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tamanioActual);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    numAleatorio(in,fin,rango,contenedorRepetidos,tamanioActual);
    cout<<rango<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}

void inicializarContenedorRepetidos( int contenedorRepetidos[], int &tamanioTotal )
{
    for( int i = 0; i < tamanioTotal; i++ )
        contenedorRepetidos[i] = 0; 
}


void definirRango(int &lI, int &lS){

    cout<<"Ingresa Inicio de Rango : ";
    cin>>lI;

    cout<<"Ingresa Final de Rango : ";
    cin>>lS;

}

void numAleatorio(int lI, int lS, int &rango, int contenedorR[], int &tamanioActual){

    bool registrado;
    do{
        rango = lI + rand() % (lS + 1 - lI); 

        registrado = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < tamanioActual ; i++){
            if(contenedorR[i] == rango){
                registrado = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(!registrado){
            contenedorR[tamanioActual++] = rango;
        }

    }while(registrado);

}
```